# Laravel BadMethodCallExeption Query Builder post

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-query-builder

I get this error message if I try to run my post on postman:

> BadMethodCallException
>
> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::posts()

My routes Looks like this:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function ()
{
     Route::get('posts', ['as' => 'posts', 'uses' => 'Api\PostController@index']);
}
```

And the Controller like this:

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Auth::client()->posts()->get();
        dd($posts);
        return response()->json(['data' => $posts], 200, [], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    }
}
```

My Client model:

```
class Client extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                      AuthorizableContract,
                                      CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword, HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'clients';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];


    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}
```

And my Post model:

```
namespace App;

use App\Client;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }
}
```

If I dump this: `$posts = Auth::user()->get();`

I get an Output, but I want to get the post Output.

Comment: Did you define a relationship between user and post model?

Answer (score 1):

You should define the relationship first.

```
<?php

...
class User extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
}
```

Once it has been defined, you can access the collection of posts by accessing the `posts` property. Most important, you should retrieve a single row firstly, then access the collection of posts like this:

```
$client = Client::find(1);
$posts = $client->posts;
```

Or you can serve the relationship as query builders like this:

```
$posts = App\Client::find(1)->posts()->where('name', 'tests')->get();
```

Iff it still occur the error,  You should check if `Auth::client()`return client model instance.

```
dd(Auth::Client());
```

Comment: I updated my question with the model do you mind having a look? I have a Clients table, the structure is the same as the users table. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you've defined `Auth::client()`, but judging by some of the code there is a misconception of how models are instantiated, and what `get()` does.

`get()` returns a collection of results.
`Auth::user()` already returns a user instance, when you call `Auth::user()->get()`, you are sending a second query to the database and returning a list of users.
`$user->posts()->get()` has a more conventional/memoized way of accessing the dataset, `$user->posts.

I'd recommend checking out your `Auth::client()` method and make sure you're not accidentally returning a new query.